# Why exactly is connecting/disconnecting circuits with power on dangerous?

Tags: connector, decoupling

Long ago I was reading about USB design and don't get one thing.

One advantage of USB is that it has optron decoupling and this makes connection/disconnection of powered on devices safe. This implies that direct (no decoupling) connection (as in older interface ports design) is somehow unsafe.

I read somewhere that some *transient processes* can happen on connection/disconnection and damage the circuits when there's no decoupling but can't find a simple explanation of what exactly might happen.

What exactly happens on connection/disconnection of powered devices without decoupling? What's some simple example of how damage occurs?

Comment: What is "optron decoupling"?

Comment: @endolith: Well, English is not my native language, so I did my best to find how a signalling circuit that is separated with optical coupling would be in English.

Comment: Oh.  USB does not have any optocoupling, though.

Comment: @endolith: Wow. How does it facilitate connections/disconnections of powered devices without damaging circuits?

Comment: I wrote an answer explaining it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wires and inputs act as inductors and capacitances. Often, for filtering reasons, you will also find the real components (inductors and capacitors) in addition to the system's parasitic elements. When plugging or unlplugging a device, you "hit" a resonant LC tank circuit that will cause voltage and current swings beyond the steady-state levels and that might be destructive to sensitive components like microcontrollers or memory ICs.

This happens as a step response upon connecting and disconnecting the plug. When connecting (turning on) the LC resonant tank, it will swing to twice the applied voltage. When you disconnect it, you may also get a freewheeling pulse from the energy stroed in the inductance. To make things worse, connecting or disconnecting a plug is never a clean event. If you look closely with an oscilloscope, you will notice that each connection or disconnection consists of many fast pulses, comparable but often far worse than the so-called bouncing of a switch.

There are a bunch of application notes out there about preventing circuits from this type of "hot plugging" damage, for example [Linear's AN-88](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Application%20Note/an88f.pdf), [this design feature by LTC](http://cds.linear.com/docs/LT%20Journal/LTJournal-V21N1-02-df-LTC436x-Kevin_Wong.pdf) or [this app'note](http://www.rgpower.com/Start-Up%20Transient%20and%20Inrush%20Current.pdf).

This mechanism is true for power wires and data wires.

Also, unprotected analog or digital inputs may cause latch-up events if they are connected before the power wires are connected. This may also cause permanent damage.

This just explains how damage to physical components might occur. In addition, the software that is needed to establish the communication across hot-pluggable interfaces must be able to recognize and support hot-plugging without becoming hung-up.

Comment: Do I get it right that the LC circuit opens and "discharges" into surrounding stuff?

Comment: Yes, that's part of the problem. I've edited the answer to include some details.

Comment: almost a -1: There's some truth here, but clouded by your LC discussions which are really not very relevant. LC energy is minimal compared to ESD.

Comment: Latchup is the key point here, and the reason that USB (and all other hotplug connectors) make power connections before data and break power connections after data.

Answer (score 2):

Connecting and detaching is an issue with power pins, not data lines.  Power pins are carrying large currents, and can't be optocoupled anyway.

Inrush current is controlled by limiting the amount of capacitance that can be placed across the power lines.  The USB spec says no more than 10 µF between VBUS and GND.  See section *7.2.4.1 Inrush Current Limiting* of [the USB spec](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/).

> When a function or hub is plugged into the network, it has a certain amount of on-board capacitance between
>   VBUS and ground. In addition, the regulator on the device may supply current to its output bypass capacitance
>   and to the function as soon as power is applied. Consequently, if no measures are taken to prevent it, there could
>   be a surge of current into the device which might pull the VBUS on the hub below its minimum operating level.
>   Inrush currents can also occur when a high-power function is switched into its high-power mode. This problem
>   must be solved by limiting the inrush current and by providing sufficient capacitance in each hub to prevent the
>   power supplied to the other ports from going out of tolerance. An additional motivation for limiting inrush
>   current is to minimize contact arcing, thereby prolonging connector contact life.

There's also a minimum of 1 µF of capacitance to suppress the effects of detaching.  Disconnecting can cause a voltage spike from the inductance of the cable, but it's not considered harmful.  See *7.2.4.2 Dynamic Detach* of the USB spec:

> When a device is detached from the network with power flowing in the cable, the inductance of the cable will
>   cause a large flyback voltage to occur on the open end of the device cable. This flyback voltage is not
>   destructive. Proper bypass measures on the hub ports will suppress any coupled noise [from one USB device to another]. The frequency range of
>   this noise is inversely dependent on the length of the cable, to a maximum of 60 MHz for a one-meter cable.
>   This will require some low capacitance, very low inductance bypass capacitors on each hub port connector. The
>   flyback voltage and the noise it creates is also moderated by the bypass capacitance on the device end of the
>   cable. Also, there must be some minimum capacitance on the device end of the cable to ensure that the inductive flyback on the open end of the cable does not cause the voltage on the device end to reverse polarity.
>   A minimum of 1.0 μF is recommended for bypass across VBUS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the term "optron decoupling", but would suggest a few reasons that, in general, connection and disconnection of live devices is problematic:

1. Some devices can be unhappy if certain combinations of connections are made, but some other connections are not.  For example, a device which has power, ground, and data-in, might source a significant amount of current into the data line if power and data are connected but ground is not.  With some connector designs, such combinations of connections may occur, especially if the connection isn't inserted or removed perfectly straight.

   Many devices may behave oddly on power-up.  If the entire system is powering up at once, everything can be held in reset until things are stable.  If a newly plugged in device outputs random junk for a little while on startup, the rest of the system might interpret that junk as real data.

   Some boards have circuitry that draws almost no current once VDD drops to a volt or so.  Powering off the main device with such a board plugged in may discharge the storage caps completely (since the main device may draw current when VDD is down to a volt, even if nothing on the plug-in board does).  If such a board is unplugged and replugged, it might not see VDD go all the way to ground, and may thus not restart correctly when it's reinserted.

It's possible to design devices so hot-plugging will "usually" be safe, and it's possible to add various amounts of protection to make it be unconditionally safe, but in the absence of specific design for hot-plugging, one should be careful.